# maven how to configuration xml file into pom.xml

Tags: java, maven

when running at cmd normally command is java -jar xxx.jar param1.
my command is java -jar  n2n-adaptor-cimbr-news-pdf-jar-with-dependencies.jar hostserver.xml

how to conficuration hostserver.xml at pom.xml? so tat no need run param at cmd.

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>n2n</groupId>
<artifactId>n2n-adaptor-cimbr-news-pdf</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <main.class>com.n2n.newsPDF.MainNewsCIMBRHostServer</main.class>
</properties>
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!-- We specify the Maven compiler plugin as we need to set it to Java 
                1.8 -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>


    <plugins>
        <!-- Maven Assembly Plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- get all project dependencies -->
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <!-- MainClass in mainfest make a executable jar -->
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                <suiteXmlFile>${project.build.directory}/resources/hostserver2.xml</suiteXmlFile>
              </suiteXmlFiles>


            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
    <resources>
    <resource>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <includes>
             <include>hostserver2.xml</include>
         </includes>
    </resource>

</resources>
</build>
```

after i make configuration it can't running when i run java -jar  n2n-adaptor-cimbr-news-pdf-jar-with-dependencies.jar.

please kindly advice.

Thanks
Sharon

Comment: Do you want to give it as a maven parameter ? Will that be good for you?

Comment: how to do for maven parameter?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem you need to solve within Java, not Maven. You define the parameters of your Java Main class. If you want to replace command line parameters with resources, this is the place to go.